# PHP AJAX, I want more faster then it

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making Ajax login form, for 2d security (mobile/mail), and this script is so slow what I made.
After 2 sec it echo 1, on mobile on and fsocietyF on, I need more faster then it, if anyone want think near me.
For more text..

```
session_start();
include('admin/phppath/d.php');

if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    if(@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    {
        if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token2']) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `signup9501` WHERE email = '$email'";
            $r = mysqli_query($c,$q);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
            $securityF = $row['securityF'];
            $onoff = $row['onoff'];

            if($onoff == 'mobile' && $securityF == 'on'){
                echo 1;
            }else if($onoff == 'email' && $securityF == 'on'){
                echo 1;
            }

            $rowpassword = $row['password'];
            $blocked = $row['blocked'];

            if (password_verify("$password", $rowpassword) && $blocked != '1') {
                $usrid = $row['id'];
                $usernum = $row['phone'];

                if($onoff == 'off' && $securityF == 'off' || $onoff == 'on' && $securityF == 'on'){
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    echo 3;
                }else if($onoff == 'email' && $securityF == 'on'){
                    $code = rand(1111,9999);
                    $upq = "UPDATE `signup9501` SET `emailcode` = '$code' WHERE `signup9501`.`id` = $usrid";
                    $upr = mysqli_query($c,$upq);

                    if($upr){
                        echo 1;
                        $_SESSION['path'] = $email;
                        mail("$email", 'Welcome.io 2D security', "Code: $code", null, '-fsupport@prado.io');
                    }else{
                        echo 0;
                    }
                }else if($onoff == 'mobile' && $securityF == 'on') {
                    $code = rand(1111,9999);
                    $upq = "UPDATE `signup9501` SET `smscode` = '$code' WHERE `signup9501`.`id` = $usrid";
                    $upr = mysqli_query($c,$upq);

                    if($upr){
                        include ( "admin/eng/src/NexmoMessage.php" );
                        $nexmo_sms = new NexmoMessage('3241fdsg', '5431gdsgs1243252'); 
                        $info = $nexmo_sms->sendText( "$usernum", "Prado.io", "SMS Code: $code");
                        $_SESSION['path'] = $email;
                    }else{
                        echo 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo 5;
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: http://prado.io/admin/eng/logout.php');
        }
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://prado.io/admin/eng/logout.php');
    }
}
else {
    header('Location: http://prado.io/admin/eng/logout.php');
}
```

Comment: Actually the consumed in sending email or message not script.

Comment: header location not work in `ajax`. return `false` and handle it in js

Comment: thank you, so i can't make it more faster then now?